# C return null if read 0 is empty

Tags: c

How to verify if the standard input is empty in C ?
I have a project for school and we are only allowed to use malloc, write, read and free, but the only solutions i find on the web use functions I am not allowed to use.
My read works perfectly except when you don't put anything in the input.

Here is my code :

```
char *ft_get_buffer(void)
{
    char    buf[10];
    int             ret;
    int             count;
    char    *result;

    count = 0;
    result = "";
    while (1)
    {
            ret = read(0, buf, 10);
            count += ret;
            if (ret < 10)
            {
                    buf[ret] = '\0';
                    result = ft_ralloc(buf, result, count);
                    break ;
            }
            else
                    result = ft_ralloc(buf, result, count);
    }
    return (result);
}
```

echo "test" | ./mybinary // works fine 
echo ./mybinary // infinite loop

Comment: This program ended soon on [Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/0VH7sPB6aFUkoqiO) with disabling `ft_ralloc`. Try debugging by printing `ret`, or the trouble may be in `ft_ralloc`.

Comment: read() returns -1 if there's an i/o error. Think about this. What does your code do in that case?

Comment: Did you try `echo "test" | ./mybinary` with `test` being of size `0`?

Comment: **Is** the program to function a specified when reading from the console **also**?

Comment: I actually try to get the -1 from read(), but we stop at the first read() call.

Comment: when indenting code, do not use tabs.  Because each word processor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.

Comment: this line: `result = "";`  is not correct.  it has `result` pointing to a NUL string in readonly memory.   Suggest: `result = NULL`;

Comment: this line: `echo ./mybinary`, on linux, will output: "./mybinary", not pass 'nothing' to the executable `./mybinary`   Suggest writing the command line more like: `echo | ./mybinary` or `echo "test" | ./mybinary`

Comment: when the returned value from `read()` is 0 ( I.E. EOF) then a character is placed into buf ('\0') but `count` is not incremented (could still be =0).  Then the call to `ft_ralloc()` is made, with an unchanged `count`.  The result is the char string pointed to by `result` will not be properly terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read()` will block unless encountering EOF or a signal event occurs.

So the code will 'sit' on the `read()` until one of 4 things happens:

1. the requested number of `char`s are input — returns request `char` count
2. EOF is encountered — returns number of `char`s read, which can be `0`
3. a signal occurs — execution path is exited
4. an I/O error occurs — returns `-1`

To check for any return condition **immediately** check the value of `ret` before using that value for any purpose.

Check for:

1. `ret ==` requested number of `char`s — then loop to read more
2. `0 <= ret <` requested number of `char`s — EOF encountered, handle accordingly
3. `0 > ret` — error occurred, handle error

Comment: Thanks for this amazing explanation.